# Properly remove a scrollView in Corona SDK

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

In my game I have a scrollview widget declared inside a function, and I want to remove that scrollview using another function, something like this:

```
local function createScrollView(event)
if(event.phase=="ended")then
    local function scrollListener( event )
        local phase = event.phase
        local direction = event.direction

        if "began" == phase then
            --print( "Began" )
        elseif "moved" == phase then
            print( "Moved" )
        elseif "ended" == phase then
            --print( "Ended" )
        end

        -- If the scrollView has reached it's scroll limit
        if event.limitReached then
            if "up" == direction then
                print( "Reached Top Limit" )
            elseif "down" == direction then
                print( "Reached Bottom Limit" )
            elseif "left" == direction then
                print( "Reached Left Limit" )
            elseif "right" == direction then
                print( "Reached Right Limit" )
            end
            end
            return true
        end

        -- Create a ScrollView
        local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
        {
            left = display.contentWidth/2-130,
            top = display.contentHeight/2-165,
            width = 440,
            height = 300,
            bottomPadding = 10,
            id = "onBottom",
            backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
            verticalScrollDisabled = false,
            listener = scrollListener,
        }
    end
end
local function removeScrollView(event)
    if(event.phase==ended)then
        if scrollView then
            scrollView:removeSelf()
            scrollView = nil
        end
    end
end
```

It doesn't return any error, but I can see that the scrollView still exists because the Corona Terminal keeps printing "moved".

Do you know how could I remove it?

Comment: quick fix would be to remove `local` from `local scrollView = widget.newScrollView` to make it global and reachable from `removeScrollView`. I suspect there is a nicer way using corona's event system.

Comment: Please do not simply remove the local and make it global. You're setting yourself up for problems in the future. Please take the time and learn about scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
local scrollView ------------EDITED

local function createScrollView(event)
 if(event.phase=="ended")then
   local function scrollListener( event )
     local phase = event.phase
     local direction = event.direction

    if "began" == phase then
        --print( "Began" )
    elseif "moved" == phase then
        print( "Moved" )
    elseif "ended" == phase then
        --print( "Ended" )
    end

    -- If the scrollView has reached it's scroll limit
    if event.limitReached then
        if "up" == direction then
            print( "Reached Top Limit" )
        elseif "down" == direction then
            print( "Reached Bottom Limit" )
        elseif "left" == direction then
            print( "Reached Left Limit" )
        elseif "right" == direction then
            print( "Reached Right Limit" )
        end
        end
        return true
    end

    -- Create a ScrollView
    ---EDITED---------------------
   scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
        left = display.contentWidth/2-130,
        top = display.contentHeight/2-165,
        width = 440,
        height = 300,
        bottomPadding = 10,
        id = "onBottom",
        backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
        verticalScrollDisabled = false,
        listener = scrollListener,
    }
 end
end

local function removeScrollView(event)
 if(event.phase==ended)then
    if scrollView then
        scrollView:removeSelf()
        scrollView = nil
    end
 end
end
```

So that you can remove the scroll view in the removeScrollView function.

Comment: Thank you very much Kumar KS! It works! Now what if I like to change the scrollview parameters? For example, how can I change the scrollView's "Left" parameter inside the "removeScrollView" function instead of delete the scroll view itself? Thanks again.

Comment: You can use object:setScrollWidth(), object:setScrollHeight() to change the width and height of it. Pls refer here https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html